# Can I ask a question that has duplicates, with answers none of which I can understand?

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicates

I want to ask a question about the Hierarchy Problem and I searched for previous questions. Each of the duplicates has 1 single answer each, and none of the answers is pitched at my own level, (which is somewhere between the end of a QM course and the lowest slopes of QFT.)

That's the way it goes on this site sometimes, and that's ok, I am just unlucky enough not to get the spread of answers that some other questions get.

I can rephrase the title, but essentially I am asking the same question, just looking for a startup (simpler) answer until, if ever, I can follow the current answers on this site.

Apologies if I missed a question that IS at my level, I just could not see one.

Comment: Tip: Link to the similar posts (and preferably explain why they don't provide adequate answers) in order to not get closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Sounds like good advice. What I seem to have noticed is that a question gets closed because it's a duplicate, but then when you look at the so-called duplicate, it isn't the same question, and the answer just doesn't answer the question. Then on the closed question you can read _this question has already been answered_ when it hasn't.

Comment: Note that sometimes a post is closable or doesn't fit the Phys.SE Q&A format for other reasons. In such cases it can get closed as a duplicate, not because it is an exact duplicate, or the duplicate has answers at the time of writing, but to guide OP (and readers with a similar question) in the right direction.

Comment: One thing I'd like to emphasize: make sure you are asking _one_ question. Or (for advanced users) a set of questions that are so closely related they might as well count as one.

Comment: @Qmechanic    This must be a somewhat common problem, with my particular question it may akin to trying to explain to a dog how his food comes in cans but I will ask. Thanks very much

Comment: @DavidZ ok, I have told that same idea to new users a few times myself. Thanks

Comment: count_to_10 : why don't you just ask the question **What is the solution to the Hierarchy problem?**

Answer (score 7):

One other thought is that, if it's essentially the same question as one already posted & answered but at a higher level than what you want, then you can always [**offer a bounty**](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) on the question with the specific request of a lower level answer.

Comment: Thanks Kyle, I might end up doing that after reading up over the weekend.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can. If you have that problem then there is a significant chance that others will in the future, and having a thread at that level will make the site a better resource overall.

However, you need to be very careful to explain how your question is different from the previous iterations - in this case in terms of level. Carefully explain what you do and do not know about the topic. List all the previous iterations that you can find, and for each of them explain why you find them confusing and particularly where you got lost - that will make it easier for your answerers to know what level to pitch their posts.

Comment: Thanks Emilio, I think this must be a general problem for lots of users, either one unsuitable answer or none at all.   I can rephrase it no problem.